# Bibtex error from style file, missing bibstyle

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm attempting to use latex on linux to write a paper for the journal "Risk Analysis".  They supply a style file which has code in it for references.  The example they give has the actual references embedded in the .tex file, however I want to draw citations and references from a .bib file.  When I look in the supplied style file, in the references section there is no specification of the bibliography style but I know that they want the references in national library of medicine (nlm) format.  Is there a line I can add to the style file that will correct this error and format both citations and references in nlm style?

I can provide a mwe if that helps.  Thanks.

> Process started
>
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian) The top-level
>   auxiliary file: risajam1.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while
>   reading file risajam1.aux (There was 1 error message)
>
> Process exited with error(s)

Comment: It would help if you provided a proper [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Currently your question is simply too vague.

Comment: Does your LaTeX file contain a `\bibliographystyle` instruction? Separately, what's the name of the bib style file provided by the journal?

Comment: Thanks Mico, no there is no \bibilographystyle  instruction in either the class file, which is called "risa.cls", or in the .tex example file that they supply.  I have searched and googled for hours and not been able to find a style file that correlates with the "National Library of Medicine", any suggestions there?

Comment: @JimMaas I cannot find the risa.cls file anywhere - is there an online source for this?